# Is there are word that means "contrived example" without a negative connotation?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have been using the word *strawman* to describe source code that is extremely simplified or contrived to illustrate some syntax or usage of something where the actual source code is irrelevant and the contrivance is not important much less a *negative connotation*.

#### Motivation:

I want to convey that the specific example is **not** relevant as a discussion point for criticism and that the focus is the syntax usage of the annotations that start with `@` without having to give a long disclaimer. That said, it is for StackOverflow so either one is probably a waste of time since 99% of the time over there people do not read for comprehension.

#### Here is a(n) ?????? example:

I would like to replace the word *strawman* with something more semantically positive. This is just showing how to use the annotations, the actual code is irrelevant. *Pseudo* is not semantically correct here as this is actual correct executable code.

> Here is a **strawman** example:
>
> ```
> @JsonCreator()
> public static Item construct(@JsonProperty("col1") String col1, @JsonProperty("col2") String col2) {
>   this(col1, col2, col1 + col2 + "some other stuff");
> }
>
> private Item(final String col1, final String col2, final String col3) {
>   this.col1 = col1;
>   this.col2 = col2;
>   this.col3 = col3;
> }
> ```

I have researched here and the general internet and can not find anything suitable. I would even accept a non-English term if it was semantically what I am looking for.

Comment: hypothetical example

Comment: No, there are no words meaning *contrived example* without a negative connotation.

*Contrived* is a great example of the difference between *made by man* and *naturally ordained*… and *naturally ordained* to most people matches *divinely ordained.*

That seems purely positive but on second thought, is *made by man* equivalent to, or might it be less than *naturally ordained*?

Comment: Maybe "constructed" rather than "contrived"?

Comment: What's wrong with just saying "example"?

Comment: @curiousdannii - I want to convey that the specific example is **not** relevant as a discussion point for criticism and that the focus is the syntax usage of the annotations that start with `@` without having to give a long disclaimer. That said, it is for StackOverflow so either one is probably a waste of time since 99% of the time over there people do not read for comprehension.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Just call it an example. You can remove any irrelevant details from the code, such as replacing the code bodies with ...

Comment: @curiousdannii - then you get downvoted for non-compilable code, it is a lose-lose situation if you have spent a non-trivial time on the site.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Ah, well that sucks. Not really a language question though. I can't see why simply saying a plain "example" won't suffice. Maybe you could edit the question to show a full post and the kind of responses you want to avoid?

Comment: @curiousdannii - thanks your questions prompted me down a search path on google translate that I had not considered. I found just what I was looking for using google translate, it suggested [this](https://translate.google.com/#en/es/artificial%20example), if you are willing to post it as an answer I will upvote and accept it! I think *artificial* is what I am going to use.

Comment: Here is an ***illustrative*** example

Comment: @JEL - just because most people use it incorrectly do not make it correct. `pseudo-code` is not executable code in any specific language, I specifically explain why this word is semantically not correct in my question.

Comment: Keeping it informal: "Here's a hokey example of what I mean". Hokey meaning "obviously contrived": https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hokey It's use lets whoever you're talking with that you don't want to get all pedantic over the details of the thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try ***illustrative***

defined by [American Heritage Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/illustrative) <sup>1</sup> as

> Acting or serving as an illustration.

---

<sup>1</sup><sup><sub>American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. Copyright © 2016 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. Published by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. All rights reserved.</sub></sup>

Answer (score 0):

You could try ***mockup***

([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mock-up))

> 2. a working sample (as of a magazine) for reviewing format, layout, or content

If you want a fancier word, you could try ***[exemplar](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exemplar)*** or ***[epitome](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epitome)***.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding code that is meant to illustrate usage, I think **pedagogical** works well - it's certainly carries no negative connotation.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pedagogical):

> **pedagogical**
>
> of, relating to, or befitting a teacher or education - pedagogical methods

Thus, *pedagogical code* becomes code that is intended to teach.

---

In the context of code that is overly simplified, I think **elementary** works well.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elementary):

> **elementary**
>
> 1. **a**: of, relating to, or dealing with the simplest elements or principles of something

There is no negative connotation when used in a teaching/academic context.  For example, *Elementary Number Theory* - referring to number theory without the use of analytic or geometric methods.

Perhaps combine the two.